# I am Getting The Errordatabase.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException in Android

Tags: android

Hello I am working with Android i want to be able to catch the error when Cursor doesn't find any values inside the Database because the application crashes when The Database inside it is empty.

Thank you!

```
public Cursor FetchData(PDatabase dob) {

        SQLiteDatabase SQ = dob.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {PTable.TableInfo.USER_NAME, PTable.TableInfo.USER_PASS};
        Cursor CR = SQ.query(PTable.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        return CR;
    }
```

I want to apply and catch or if else to catch the error so that the app doesn't stop

Comment: post error log here.

Comment: where your app crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code hope that will help you

```
if (CR.moveToFirst()) {

    for (int i = 0; i < CR.getCount(); i++) {
        // do your stuff here 
        db.close();
    }
}else{
    // handle response here if no value found
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys much of an help